# How do I go about installing 7.1.1 in my nexus 5x?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, 7.0-nougat

My question pretty much says everything. I have a nexus 5x with 7.0 rooted and (nougat) installed. I have also flashed kali net hunter image on it. I have google assistant installed. Now, I would like to update my phone to 7.1.1. I want my phone rooted along with google assistant. Nethuneter is not necessary because it consumes a lot of my memory and storage. For my recovery, I have TWRP installed. Kindly suggest me the best way to deal with this.

Answer (score -1):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/orig-development/wip-aosp-nougat-nexus-5-t3446875

This is what you're looking for..

Comment: OP has a Nexus **5X**.